# Declaring an extern struct template in header file for global use in c files

Tags: c

My goal is to declare and define a single structure **template** in my header file. I then wish to use this template to declare and define **individual** structures in my c files.

This is a rough example of what I'm aiming for:

**header file**

```
#include <bool.h>

extern struct options 
{
    extern bool aflag;
    extern bool cflag;
    extern bool dflag;
} option1;
...
```

**c file**

```
#include "header.h"

struct options option1;
void function(void) 
{
option1.aflag = true;
option1.cflag = true;
option1.dflag = true;
}
...
```

I want this to result in the structure `option1` being globally visible. The global contents should be `aflag = true`, `cflag = true`, and `dflag = true`.

When I say global, I mean that the contents `aflag = true`, `cflag = true`, and `dflag = true` (defined in another c file) should now be usable in yet a second c file if I wish. The only reference being the header file with the structure.

However, as I expected, this example contains multiple errors. I have only recently learned the basics of structures and am unsure of how to achieve exactly what I'm looking for. What can I try next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare a structure you define a type.

If you want a `struct` to be globally visible then you need tp define a variable not a type.

So you can do something like this in your foo.h header file:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    double baz;
};

extern struct foo globally_visible_foo_yay;
```

And then in the foo.c file you want:

```
#include "foo.h"
struct foo globally_visible_foo_yay = {.bar = 42, .baz = 42.0};
```

And in some other C file you can then use the globally visible struct by including the header.