# Extern struct builds on aCC (HP-UX) but not on macOS (Xcode)

Tags: arrays, c, xcode, struct, extern

I have the following headers file that I share across two source files:

sth.h:

```
#define NBALLS 10
#define NBOTS 2

struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}bots[NBOTS];

struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}balls[NBALLS];
```

That I consume the same way across two source files:
a.c:

```
#include "sth.h"
void makeBalls(void) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=1;i<NBALLS;i++) {
        balls[i].px = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        balls[i].py = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        //pz[i] = 0.9;
        balls[i].pz = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        balls[i].vx = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
        balls[i].vy = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
        balls[i].vz = -1.0+randf()*2.0;
    }
}
```

and b.c:

```
#include "sth.h"
void makeBots(void) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=1;i<NBOTS;i++) {
        bots[i].px = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        bots[i].py = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        //pz[i] = 0.9;
        bots[i].pz = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
        bots[i].vx = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
        bots[i].vy = -1.5+randf()*3.0;
        bots[i].vz = -1.0+randf()*2.0;
    }
}
```

In HP-UX, it builds and runs fine.
In latest macOS, it complains of duplicate symbols.

If I make the following change in sth.h:

```
static struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}bots[NBOTS];

static struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}balls[NBALLS];
```

It builds and runs fine. However, naturally, my program doesn't work.

I tried following the recommendation here:
[Declaring an extern struct template in header file for global use in c files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393964/declaring-an-extern-struct-template-in-header-file-for-global-use-in-c-files)

But then Xcode complains that

```
bots[i].px = MIN + randf()*(MAX-MIN);
```

is not a vector or pointer.

I'm very puzzled to why it works under HP-UX. I'm learning C (very beginner) and trying to make sure my code remains portable and also learning how to handle endianness issues.

Thanks, as always.

edit:
The change I made according to the recommendation, answering to the comment below:
sth.h:

```
#define NBALLS 10
#define NBOTS 2

struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}botsZ[NBOTS];

struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}ballsZ[NBALLS];

extern struct botsZ bots;
extern struct ballsZ balls;
```

Xcode returns on a.c and b.c: "Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector" on every line of the function inside the for loop.

And why does aCC build it fine? I think MIPSPro also builds it ok (I will test once I return from trip)

Comment: Question updated, thank you.

Comment: Ah, ok, good. I think I see the problem and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`botsZ` is an array of `2` instances of an anonymous struct defined like htis:

```c
struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
};
```

and here's the definition of that array, in the header file:

```c
#define NBOTS 2

struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
}botsZ[NBOTS];
```

The following

```c
extern struct botsZ bots;
```

declares an extern variable named `bots` with the type `struct botsZ`, but there is no such type. `botsZ` is an instance.

---

Suggestion:

- Define the `struct`s and `typedef`s you need in the `.h` file
- `extern` declare the instances
- *define* instances in the `.c` file

Example:

**sth.h**

```c
#ifndef STH_H
#define STH_H

#define NBALLS 10
#define NBOTS 2

typedef struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
} botsZ;

typedef struct {
    float px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz;
} ballsZ;

extern botsZ bots[NBOTS];
extern ballsZ balls[NBALLS];

#endif
```

**sth.c**

```c
#include "std.h"

botsZ bots[NBOTS] = {0};
ballsZ balls[NBALLS] = {0};
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ted. I appreciate the thorough explanation.
Now, what's bugging me. Any idea why it builds (and works perfectly) under HP-UX?

I'll be able to try in a week, abroad now, but will surely get back.

I'm still beginning and trying to keep things portable, so this is really puzzling me.

Comment: @Shiunbird You're welcome! In your original code at the top you defined `bots` and `balls` in the header file which means every translation unit will define them, which it's an ODR ([_one definition rule_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)) violation: _"The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is **undefined**"_ - so it may look like it's working but it can also do unexpected things. With my changes it should be working on both platforms.

Comment: Beautiful! It builds and runs fine, no errors and no warnings. And I actually understand it now =)

Comment: @Shiunbird Lovely! Glad it helped!